# Entity Framework Code First Error - EntityType 'Variable' has no key defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 5 Code First in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project and I'm getting the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Variable' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Variables' is based on type 'Variable' that has no keys defined.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Variable' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Variables' is based on type 'Variable' that has no keys defined.

This has been driving me nuts for the last hour. I have searched my solution and have nothing called 'Variable' at all!

My context looks like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IDisposedTracker
{

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; set; }
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int Uid { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Task> Tasks { get; internal set; }
}
```

Task looks like this:

```
public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int Uid { get; set; }

    public string Id;

    public string Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for an relationship with no table to relate to.

There needs to be a place to place the object Tasks

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IDisposedTracker
{

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisposed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did not realize this question was from 2012